# Not able to update existing application using Itunes

Tags: iphone

We have developed the iphone application version 1 and installed it in the iphone device when i try to install its version 2 or its updates via itunes than it doesn;t syn with the iphone and the run the last app that have been installed and i think it picks up from cache
 i want it in a manner that it overwrite the app over on the last version and pick updates from second one that the data can be retained between the both of the the versions using itunes .

Let us know how to update previous version app with new version app using ITunes.
Thanks 
Balraj

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to bump the version number in the .plist file? iTunes doesn't use the file date to decide you have a newer build, it apparently checks the version number of the app bundle.

Comment: I did, but without success. I have called to Apple Store, and they said to me that in a pair of days they will answer me.